# How to rotate an item from a specific point in Qml?

Tags: qt, rotation, qml, pivot

I need to rotate an item from a specific point but I have not found a way to do this.

From the documentation I get the notion that the origin in Rotation is supposed to be the pivot point but this is not the case.

I don't know what the origin is supposed to be but it most certainly is not the pivot point.

It doesn't matter what I put in the origin, the item always rotates around it's `tranformOrigin`.

Changing `transformOrigin` works but like I stated, I need to change the pivot point to a custom location.

Any ideas how to make that happen or do you see something wrong in the code?

```
Item {
    id: mainItem

    transform: Rotation {
        origin.x: 20
        origin.y: 20
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "white"

        Component.onCompleted: state = "rotated"

        transitions: Transition {
            RotationAnimation {
                duration: 10000
                direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
            }
        }

        states: State {
            name: "rotated"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: mainItem
                rotation: 360
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there seems to be confusion I'll add some explanation about the code. This is code for an object that I'm adding dynamically to the scene.

Comment: My mistake was using rotation property of item. Transform: Rotation {angle: 20} works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-rotation.html shows the `Rotation` object having `origin` and `angle` properties and that it can be applied directly to the `Rectangle` transform property. The following demonstrates how with a simple animation:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    Rectangle {
        x: parent.width / 2
        y: parent.height / 2
        width: 100; height: 100
        border.color: "white"
        color: "transparent"
        transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: 50
            origin.y: 150
            NumberAnimation on angle {
                from: 0
                to: 360
                running: true
                duration: 10000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACLnicbZDBToRADIbvPEXDAyCr0cN4Mp68GNc3GGCAZqElpZPVGN7d2SHgsviHw7TfP/SfYj+wKBz16LE8Jbgps1cmFe7G5MM2Dn4SCCpseWqEPVUGPl2plpouMCi5YzGQFl0wpDBF85Uh1hd9GRisONLsjJW2cAf3K/teWeuwaXUDo93AIc+fYcaxWHnBUjnJliDnFtWlK13aKpbGecgfjM2apQ9vYrWKTFeJL2LBBikL4R/z/0BIfrgh774vnLwQ9vMPw3e7i0W1cBid7/rKBh6e9n3xREiNCcG929HKS5wY15Pvb3fMw2hgTZa9UY0UtrVxTsn2NCXTL9uhkkk)

Alternatively, you can set `x` and `y` of your rectangle so it creates a new pivot point. Then, you apply the rotation not to the rectangle but the parent item, i.e.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Item {
            id: frame
            Rectangle {
                x: 200
                y: -30
                width: 100
                height: 100
                border.color: "white"
                color: "transparent"
            }
            NumberAnimation on rotation {
                from: 0
                to: 360
                duration: 10000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACcHicdY/BboMwDIbvPIXV+1C3SjvkNu3EZWr3BiEEiEpsZBx108S7L8CoxsKsHPz/+WLnd74nFrjIJThzzdxG5q+EwtQN2Vk3Fr4yiOUqBX2Usyi1uTZMAaP5bo1obLoIgqGOWMGh7CJwgHGGC7H+Z8hUGk1LPOTGolgucBrLsb8Df/h1ec3a2437a/PGn+pDwdPxmNifCh5OqX1zlbQKHndetNY1rezflcSV5XxNfWud2ENCrdfCGocl6xYaN+ot+NLyCzqvxRFCPEyy9GnOmskrSL8mpOD0nPpV4HnUHGgnUkfUDwru6/MCa4cxV0JyQHTYKBAO9p88Szdm4zdk4pco)

Comment: Yeap, seems I missed the part about the angle in transform.

Answer (score 0):

With a transparent rectangle, I'm not sure what you're expecting to see, but I think you need to make the target of your property change the rectangle, not the enclosing item. See if this does what you want (I changed a few parameters):

```
Item {
id: mainItem
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    x: 100
    y: 100
    height: 100
    width: 100
    color: "red"
    antialiasing: true

    Component.onCompleted: state = "rotated"

    transitions: Transition {
        RotationAnimation {
            duration: 1000
            direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
        }
    }

    states: State {
        name: "rotated"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: rect
            rotation: 45
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to your original question: [see here.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#transformOrigin-prop)

Answer (score 0):

When I'm testing the `origin` property of the `Rotation` it always looks correct. Are you doing something special from the outside of the item?

Nevertheless you can create your own origin/pivot point by using the `transform` property. Have a look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-of-rotation-around-a-point-other-than-the-origin) to get some more mathematical insights.

Basically:

1. Translate object to pivot point
2. Rotate object certain angle
3. Translate back

```
property point pivotPoint: Qt.point(20, 20)

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "transparent"
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "red"

    transform: [
        Translate {
            x: pivotPoint.x
            y: pivotPoint.y
        },
        Rotation {
            angle: 45
        },
        Translate {
            x: -pivotPoint.x
            y: -pivotPoint.y
        }
    ]
}
```