How to correctly place and animate image on QML?
I started learning Qt and QML with a simple (and orrible :D) project of an Automotive Cluster Instrument interface. Below you can find the code for my QML interface:
// CircularGauge.qml

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    id: root
    property real value: 0
    property real maxValue: 100
    property real minValue: 0
    property real step: 10
    property real startAngle: -135
    property real endAngle: 135

    width: 400
    height: 400

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 300
        height: 300

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

            var centerX = width / 2;
            var centerY = height / 2;
            var radius = 140;
            var startRad = root.startAngle * Math.PI / 180;
            var endRad = root.endAngle * Math.PI / 180;

            // Draw translucent background
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8)";
            ctx.fill();

            // Outer gradient ring
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, height);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "#3f51b5");
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "#2196f3");

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startRad, endRad);
            ctx.lineWidth = 20;
            ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
            ctx.stroke();

            // Draw notches and values
            for (var i = root.minValue; i <= root.maxValue; i += root.step) {
                var ratio = (i - root.minValue) / (root.maxValue - root.minValue);
                var angle = startRad + ratio * (endRad - startRad);

                var x1 = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * (radius - 20);
                var y1 = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * (radius - 20);
                var x2 = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
                var y2 = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius;

                // Notches
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
                ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
                ctx.stroke();

                // Values
                if (i % root.step === 0) {
                    var xText = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * (radius - 40);
                    var yText = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * (radius - 40);
                    ctx.font = "16px sans-serif bold";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                    ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                    ctx.fillText(i.toFixed(0), xText, yText);
                }
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;

            // Guideline
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(width / 2, height / 2);
            ctx.lineTo(width / 2 + Math.cos(Math.PI * -135 / 180) * (width / 2 - 10),
                       height / 2 + Math.sin(Math.PI * -135 / 180) * (height / 2 - 10));
            ctx.stroke();

        }
    }

    Image {
        id: needle
        source: "qrc:/images/needle.png"
        width: canvas.width * 0.02 
        height: canvas.height * 0.5
        anchors.centerIn: canvas
        property real angleOffset: 85 
        transformOrigin: Item.Bottom
        // transform: Rotation {
        //     // origin.x: needle.width / 2
        //     // origin.y: needle.height * 0.8
        //     angle: needle.angleOffset + root.startAngle + (root.value - root.minValue) / (root.maxValue - root.minValue) * (root.endAngle - root.startAngle)
        // }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 10
        height: 10
        color: "red"
        radius: 5
    } 
}


//Main.qml

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    title: "Automotive Cluster Demo"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#1a237e" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#0d47a1" }
        }

        GridLayout {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            columns: 2
            columnSpacing: 50

            
            CircularGauge {
                id: speedGauge
                label: "Speed"
                unit: "km/h"
                value: 0
                minValue: 0
                maxValue: 240
                step: 20
                startAngle: -135
                endAngle: 135
            }

            CircularGauge {
                id: rpmGauge
                label: "RPM"
                unit: "x1000"
                value: 0
                minValue: 0
                maxValue: 6
                step: 1
                startAngle: -135
                endAngle: 135
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm struggling trying to place the needle.png image right on the same position as the guideline. The result I have obtained is in the pic below:

I want first to get the right position of the needle and then add an animation that moves with a control logic that I have implemented. Any advice is welcome, also some tips to improve the code.
I tried the rotation (commented in this code) but I can't find the correct value of the angle and origin to place the needle exactly on the guideline.  I also asked ChatGPT to help on this topics but it give me always the same incorrect answer.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644994/how-to-rotate-an-item-from-a-specific-point-in-qml

To have better control of my rotation, I typically use a parent Item as an anchor point, e.g.
    Item {
        id: needle
        anchors.centerIn: canvas
        property real angleOffset: 85 
        rotation: needle.angleOffset
                    + root.startAngle
                    + (root.value - root.minValue)
                      / (root.maxValue - root.minValue)
                      * (root.endAngle - root.startAngle) 
        Image {
            x: -width / 2
            y: -height
            width: canvas.width * 0.02 
            height: canvas.height * 0.5
            source: "needle.svg"
            sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
